# How to Print events and event queues in Simpy?

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I want to create a log file to store all the events that occur during the course of my simulation (possibly with timestamp) in Simpy. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

can you just box the yield statements with print / log statements?  In many ways this is the easiest and it allows you to add context data, i.e. who is creating the event.  Python has a built in logging lib called logging.  The other options are to dynamically monkey patch the event classes or sub class the event classes.  I myself just box the yield statements with logging.  I think this is the clearest way to know what is getting logged and I do not have maintain any sub classes.